# Cannot send image through cURL

Tags: php, curl, remote-server

For some reason I cannot send images through cURL to an external server. Probably something small but i've been looking at this code for hours now and still have no idea whats going wrong...

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
    'fbid' => $userProfile['id'],
    'name' => $userProfile['name'],
    'email' => $userProfile['email'],
    'gender' => $userProfile['gender'],
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'original' => '@' . UPLOAD_PATH . $imageFilename,
    'thumbnail' => '@' . UPLOAD_PATH . $thumbnailFilename,
    'cropped' => '@' . UPLOAD_PATH . $croppedImageFilename
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.com/curl.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
```

The text is getting through, if I print out $_POST on the remote server this is what I get...

```
Array (
    [fbid] => 12345
    [name] => My Name
    [email] => email@domain.com
    [gender] => male
    [title] => Image title
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated :P

Comment: Are you using `multipart/form-data` or the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget my last answer. Was too hasty. I believe the issue is that you are looking in $_POST for file uploads. File uploads are contained in $_FILES.

Try dumping the contents of $_FILES on your remote server.